# What happens when you deposit all collectibles?

Tags: guild-wars-2

On the inventory screen, if you click the gear icon, and then "Deposit All Collectibles", some stuff from your inventory will disappear.

I think the idea is that it will automatically send such items to your bank without having to make a trip there. Is this true?

What happens if your bank is full? I've been depositing copper ore this way, and now that I've finally had a chance to visit the bank, I don't see any copper ore there. Is it gone forever?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your bank in Guild Wars 2 is bifurcated - you have the Guild Bank, where you can put whatever you want (and buy storage expansions for) and you have the collections tab, which holds the most common crafting materials.

Pressing "Deposit All Collectibles" will check to see if there is room in your collections tab (stack size is 250), and if it is, it will automagically be sent there. This is one way, however - you can't "un-deposit collectibles"; you'll have to actually make it to a bank or crafting station for that!

One thing to be aware of is that Miniatures count as collectibiles, so if you have, say, a miniature Rytlock Brimstone from the Digital Deluxe edition, pressing "Deposit All Collectibles" will store your pet in the collections tab as well as that copper ore you mined.

Comment: You can absolutely remove collectables from the bank.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Right. But only when you're *at* a bank. You can "deposit collectibles" from anywhere.

Comment: Well your wording is misleading.  I DEMAND JUSTICE!.  Also, you can remove collectables from any workbench.

Comment: @RavenDreamer You can also remove items from the bank when at a crafting station, as you have full access to your bank from there.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Can, but no need to. You can craft directly from your bank / collectibles tab.

Comment: The materials I am taking out are not the ones I am using for crafting.  They are the ones I want to sell.

Comment: *facepalm* I didn't even see the other tab. I was trying to keep that stuff in the normal bank tab. This information makes a world of difference.

Comment: Also it's worth noting that any items in an 'invisible' pack will not be automatically deposited. So if you have a miniature you want to keep, be sure to put it in an invisible pack.

Comment: I would like to note that there is a difference between a 'Bank' and the 'Guild Bank'.

Answer (score 2):

If you try to deposit something that there is no space for, it will stay in your inventory.

For example mats only stack up to 250, after that, they stay in your inventory.