# What are my "bank" and "guild bank" and how do I access them?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I had the same [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/94860/what-happens-when-you-deposit-all-collectibles) as StrixVaria -- what happens when you "deposit all collectibles" in your inventory.

However, I didn't completely understand the answers -- the two banks mentioned -- how do you access them?

Are they among the menus and windows, or do you go to a map location, or something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access your own bank (which stores items in separate tabs) from:

- A banker NPC, which you can find in major cities. See:  http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Banker
- A crafting station. They (conveniently!) use the collectibles you have deposited until now. You can also manually withdraw them, but unless you want to sell them, I don't recommend it.
- There is also an premium item allowing you to summon a banker anywhere.

For further information about your personal bank, see: http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Account_vault

The guild bank can only be accessed from specific NPCs. You will find them at the same place as the personal bank NPCs. See: http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Guild_Banker

As of the Queen's Jubilee's update, the [Wallet](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Wallet) has been introduced. The Wallet is a tab on the hero panel that tracks currency for each account. Things like gold, karma and dungeon tokens are stored there instead of on the Bank.

Answer (score 4):

The Banks are both located in Lion's Arch and all the other racial cities, here are the ones in Lion's Arch:

[image]